# Examples for non-math department students to be used for Calculus course

Tags: mathematics, teaching, undergraduate, methodology, economics

This semester I am a teaching assistant for Calculus. There are many students from different departments like International Relations, Economics and more taking the course. The course is comprehensive. For example, we gave the "epsilon-delta" definition of limit, we find the derivative of functions using the definition of derivative, find the equation of tangent line that passes through a point on some function. I am trying my best to explain what are we doing during class; I draw graphs to explain formal stuff, give daily life examples while finding a delta for a given epsilon. However, I can see the pain in their face and that bothers me a lot because I want them to understand or at least pass the class with a relatively high grade.

So, can you give me some examples related to your department that I can use in Calculus, or some advice about to increase the level of understanding of the course? Any answers will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Maybe would be more suitable question for the math.stackexchange?

Comment: Ask this in the [Mathematics Educators](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange.

Comment: "give daily life examples while finding a delta for a given epsilon" I am puzzled, but intrigued, by that.  How does finding a delta for a given epsilon relate to (non-mathematical) daily life?

Comment: In short, my example was: I am cooking and in order to make my meal taste "the best" I have to add 8 gram of salt. So I said that close to the best I feel  if  I add an amount of salt between (7.9,8.1) or something between 7.5 and 8.5. As we do in taking a limit, we exclude the point 8 from the intervals, so, that was my explanation.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark, what is your opinion about my example, is there anything missing or how could it be improved?

Comment: Don't insult your hearers by inventing far-fetched examples.

Comment: Instead of the cooking example, perhaps try something like the examples I posted [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4538506).

Comment: @Karl, well, why do you think like that?

Comment: An example should not be fabricated, state the conditions and assumptions under which it is correct, and not contain parts that are pure decoration.

Comment: You're in academia, not primary school. If a prof tries to teach abstraction (or rather save me from having to abstract) like to a ten-year-old, I feel insulted.

Comment: Um, why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?  There is no shortage of calculus textbooks that contain examples and problems that are *labeled* as being relevant for this target audience.